# How to Execute Script with Parameter on a Mac?

Tags: macos, scripting

I have command line script, i need to execute it by programmatically with parameters.
How to execute script from coding? Can anyone guide me?

With Regards
Vadivelu

Comment: with what language? Obj-c, php, python, ruby, applescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) allows you to do this.